# Time complexity - Making new array and copy all elements from old array when its full n times

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

> Let be an array that used for some data with size n. if there's an
> overflow we make a new array, copy all the elements in old array to
> the new and we just make the new array bigger by 1 extra.
>
> If we have an array size of n and √n of first spots are occupied.
>
> What's the time complexity for insert n new elements?

Since we already have √n element's in the n size array. There's (n - √n) left spots for the group of size n. We insert (n-√n) of them into the array and we left with √n elements to insert. The array is full. So we have to make new arrays √n times with one added extra spot.

Time complexity:

1. insert (n - √n) elements into origin array is just O(n).
2. Copy the array size n into new array size n+1. - O(n)
3. Insert the extra element. - O(1)

We have to do steps 2 and 3 √n times.

Total: O(n) + √n*O(n) + √n*O(1) = Θ(√n*n)

Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is correct.

One aspect that wasn't mentioned is that the +1 in step 2 will only be exactly +1 on the *first* execution, but will be +2, +3, ..., +√ in the subsequent executions.

But still, if we would create an upper bound for the complexity by always assuming that this step is O(+√) for each execution, the outcome is the same (I exclude the O() of the first phase here):

O(√(+√)) = O(√ + ) = O(√)